# redhat DNS for local use only not for internet

Tags: domain-name-system

i configure a DNS for internal services and requests. but when i apply the DNS users are able to connect to the internet through my DNS . how can i block internet access through my DNS and use only for internal network 10.x.x.x for example

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! What have you tried? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? What does your config look like? Do you have any log entries from the times it didn't work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation how to use the DNS server as authoritative only without recursion.

If you'll clarify your question I'll extend the answer.